# Persist data in controller from angularJs post

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I write some angularJs code

```
var app = angular.module('registration', []);
app.controller('registrationController', ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http){
$scope.userData = {};
var registrationUrl = Routing.generate('registrationAction');
console.log(registrationUrl);
$scope.sendForm = function() {
    $http({
        'url'       : registrationUrl,
        'data'      : $.param($scope.userData),
        'method'    : 'POST',
        'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
        .success(function(data){
            if(data.response == true) {
                console.log('success');
                $location.path(Routing.generate('indexAction'));
            }
        })
        .error(function(error){
           console.log('error');
        });
}
}]);
```

In my controller

```
public function registrationAction(Request $request)
{
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $user = new Users();
        $user->setEmail($request->request->get('email'));
        $user->setPassword($request->request->get('password'));
        $user->setUsername($request->request->get('login'));
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse(['response' => true]);
    }
    return new JsonResponse(['response' => false]);
}
```

In result my data doesn't write in db and my page doesn't redirect, but in my console i doesn't have error and i have status code 200. Please, help me

Comment: `$location.path` indicate the redirect between SPA, I think you need to redirect to server..you could use `window.location.href = Routing.generate('indexAction')`

Comment: jut check your network tab from console

Comment: Whats the issue ? does your redirection is not working ? or data is not getting inserted ?

Comment: @Ganesh Ghalame all doesn't work

Comment: Just use network tab for checking whether request URI and parameters are correct. You can use this link if you want to know how to use network tab http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2014/05/06/javascript-debugging-tips-part-i-google-chrome-and-the-network-tab-2/  . One more thing just enable php error logs using `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to store data from angularJS client to symfony2 server, you should use a simple and light Request listener to handle content-types 'application/json'.

[qandidate-labs/symfony-json-request-transformer](https://github.com/qandidate-labs/symfony-json-request-transformer)

Then, in your submit form action (client), just do :

```
$scope.sendForm = function(){
    $http.post(registrationUrl, $scope.userData);
        .success(function(data){
           if(data.response == true) {
               console.log(data.response);
               $location.path(Routing.generate('indexAction'));
           }
        }).error(function(data){
            console.log("data error ...");
        });
};
```

The store action (server)

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

//...
public function registrationAction()
{
    $request = new Request();
    $request = $request->createFromGlobals();

    $user = new Users();
    $user->setEmail($request->request->get('email'));
    $user->setPassword($request->request->get('password'));
    $user->setUsername($request->request->get('login'));
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse(['response' => true]);
}
```

Comment: i try your solution. Thank you !